# How to make new "Future" instance based on function parameter in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code, "getResponse" is executed only once. How can I fix it?
I don't want to put "getResponse" inside "retry".

```
import "dart:math";

Future getResponse(int sec) async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: sec), () {
    int rand = Random().nextInt(10);
    print(rand);
    if (rand < 5) {
      return "success";
    } else {
      throw "rejected";
    }
  });
}

Future retry(Future f, [int count = 0]) async {
  try {
    return (await f);
  } catch (e) {
    if (count < 5) {
      print(e);
      retry(f, count + 1); // I think here is wrong.
    }
  }
}

void main() async => await retry(getResponse(1));
```

Function "retry" should execute getResponse until it successed

Comment: it is getting called 5 times on exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "retry" a future. Once it's done, it's done. You can however, create a new one every time, by passing a "future factory" (a function producing the relevant future) instead of the future:

```
import "dart:math";

Future getResponse(int sec) async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: sec), () {
    int rand = Random().nextInt(10);
    print(rand);
    if (rand < 5) {
      return "success";
    } else {
      throw "rejected";
    }
  });
}

// pass the factory function here
Future retry(Future Function() f, [int count = 0]) async {
  try {
    // call the function here to get a future to await
    return (await f());
  } catch (e) {
    if (count < 5) {
      print(e);
      retry(f, count + 1); 
    }
  }
}

// here, a function returning a future, instead of the future itself is passed
void main() async => await retry(() => getResponse(1));
```

The comment suggesting a loop instead of recursion is probably spot on too.